Bootstrap or bootstrap.dat
It seems to me that bootstrap and bootstrap.dat are redundant. Should we merge them? If yes, which one do we keep and why?

They do seem to be redundant, I think merging them would be a good idea. I would keep bootstrap.dat, because it has more questions, which implies it is probably the more commonly used term. It also already had a description in place.
